# Null pointer exception while comparing two different xml files

Tags: java, xml, dom, arraylist, comparison

While calling the method to compare two XML  nodes. null pointer exception is occurring. Please help me with your valuable inputs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < englishTextNodes.getLength(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < otrLangTextNode.getLength(); j++)
    {
        if( englishTextNodes.item(i).getNodeValue().toString().compareToIgnoreCase(
                 otrLangTextNode.item(j).getNodeValue().toString()) == 0 )
        {
            Results.add(englishTextNodes.item(i).getNodeValue().toString());
            break;
        }
    }
    return Results;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace of the exception. Or at the very least, mention at which line the NPE is getting thrown.

Comment: A sample XML document would be helpful too.  However a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be preferable (Java code and XML).

Answer (score 0):

Add checks to make sure the .getNodeValue() calls are not returning null. If .getNodeValue() returns null, calling .toString() will throw a null pointer exception.

You will probably want to write a comparison helper method that accounts for null values before comparing, and call that in your if statement, in order to make your code clean.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs.I changed the method from getNodeValue() to getTextContent() because getNodeValue() was storing null value,so the exception was occuring.Now it is working fine to me. Below is the changed code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < englishTextNodes.getLength(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < otrLangTextNode.getLength(); j++)
             {
 if((englishTextNodes.item(i).getTextContent().toString().compareToIgnoreCase(otrLangTextNode.item(j).getTextContent().toString()))==0)
                        {
```

Results.add("UntranslatedNodes"+englishTextNodes.item(i).getTextContent().toString());
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }